# Which automation testing certification to undertake when using Cypress, Azure and Javascript in an organization

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I am required to plan for some courses and / or certification in next 2 years.

I am an automation tester in an organization and there is no other automation tester in our company hence no internal certification available at the moment.

At the moment I am using Cypress (learning on the go) and Javascript to automate the applications in here
I am also using Azure Devops for CI process. I have also just started using yaml language

I am being asked to come with a development plan for next 18 months.
I am already thinking to do ISTQB Automation, as I have completed ISTQB Foundation years ago.

Is there any other courses or certification you can suggest for my role to share and track my development progress in automation.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps provides Test Plans service, you could find a series of documentations here: [Azure Test Plans documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops).

In addition, you could [associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops)and [Requirements traceability](http://Requirements%20traceability). Also you could [run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops).

May you achieve great progress all the time.

Comment: Thank you @Edward for your response I will look into your suggests for my years activity. Are there any certifications as well for automation testers . I am looking to undertake some certifications but unsure which automation certification will be recognized globally

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not handle issues about certifications part so I don't familiar about it, and I suggest that you could consult this question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home, which I know handles this business before. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Knowledge Seeker, does my answer help? If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.